# Why is it recommended to call registerUserNotificationSettings before registering with the push notification service

Tags: ios, ios8

I was  going to new remote notifications API of iOS 8, when I found this in the docs:

> "It is recommended that you call this method before you schedule any
>   local notifications or register with the push notification service"

I could not understand why is it said so. I have the impression that the two method calls:

> registerUserNotificationSettings

and

> registerForRemoteNotifications

are now independent and one does not effect other. Then why it is recommended to call one before another?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in Apple documentation:

> If you want your app’s remote notifications to display alerts, play sounds, or perform other user-facing actions, you must call the registerUserNotificationSettings: method to request the types of notifications you want to use. If you do not call that method, the system delivers all remote notifications to your app silently.

Comment: Well, yes, but looks like without calling registerUserNotificationSettings just registerForRemoteNotifications has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

IOS 8 , for fetch device token and register remote notification we need to apply a different process.

```
if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {

        //Right, that is the point
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }else{
        // Register for push notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }
```

///////////Again we need to define

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
```

Then we can get the device token in ios 8

Comment: This does not address the original question in any way, shape or form.